# Bootstrap Horizontal Scrolling Table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a very long table that I created and had to put horizontal scrolling on it so be able to see all the fields.

I did this by adding:

```
div.horizontal {
   width: 100%;
   height: 500px;
   overflow: auto;
}

table-layout: fixed;

.table {
   display: table;
   table-layout: fixed;
   width: 100%;
}
```

My table is then wrapped inside a container and a div like so:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="horizontal">
      <table class="table table-bordered" name="int">
...........
```

Everything is working as intended however because I am defining a height in the horizontal div, the scroll bar is in the middle of the page. However, when I use a percentage, its always 100% of the content, not of the over all page.

My goal here is to just get the scroll bar on the bottom of the browser like normal but be able to keep this full width table I have.

Here is a screenshot: [image]

As you can see, with the Defined 500px the scroll bar lands there (which is expected with a fixed width). I just assumed that using a percentage `100%` would have pushed it down to the bottom but It didnt.

Any ideas how I can get this scroll bar to the bottom of the page?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `position: fixed;` or `absolute` into `div.horizontal` styles.

Comment: That didnt work, it made  the table move but the table was stuck in the same place.

Comment: @SBB I like to add, the problem here is the most outer container's height is unknown to browser. You should either set a specific height or it will grow dynamically according to contained content. If you set its height `100%`, its height will be equal to parent element's height. By setting any element's position to fixed and height to 100% we get that element out of  context and position and size according to window object.